# woo-commerce rest API give only 10 order per call

Tags: php, api, rest, woocommerce

i am using woo-commerce api to fetch the orders. i am following this toturial: https://packagist.org/packages/woothemes/woocommerce-api. i am able to fetch 10 order per hour for given date and time like 2016-06-03T10:00. but i my store there is 20 to 25 order based on this time method and i want to fetch all order of given time in single API call. Following is my code:

```
require_once 'class-wc-api-client.php';
$consumer_key = 'ck_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; 
$consumer_secret = 'cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; 
$store_url = 'http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/'; 

$wc_api = new WC_API_Client( $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $store_url );     
$params = array( 'filter[created_at_max]' => '2016-06-03T10:00' );

$results = $wc_api->get_orders();
foreach($results->orders as $order){

    echo $order->id.' - '.$order->created_at;
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

also i have tried filter like below but no luck:

```
$params = array( 'filter[created_at_min]' => '2016-06-03T10:00' );
```

please help me fetch all the order for given time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WooCommerce is limited to 10 results per page as a default. Add a filter `?filter[limit]` with an amount (max 250) to get more results per page or add `?page=2` to get the next 10 results.

Edit: If you are using the latest WooCommerce, you can change the amount of results per page by using `?per_page` as a param: `?per_page=15` instead of the filter param describe above.

For details, check the docs: http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#pagination

Edit: Updated link to docs

Comment: thank for your valuable comment. my script can fetch all order now. thanks again.

Comment: @stephangroen any idea how to set the limit to maximum?. I tried using ?per_page=maximum was not working.

Comment: You cannot add maximum. The maximum is 200 I thought, but newer API's might have 100 as maximum. Having too many results per page will cause serious load on the webserver the shop is running on.